# How to convert JSON message into ISO 8583

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-security, bson, iso8583

I need your help. I work in Spring, and would like to know how to convert a JSON message into ISO 8583 message.

Is there any other way to encrypt a JSON message? For example, I have a JSON object like this:

```
{"id":12,"desc":"tutorial"}
```

My goal is to make the message more secure.

Comment: ISO 8583 is a Financial transaction card originated message format, how does that apply to the JSON in the question? how does "make the message more secure" apply?

Answer (score 3):

IOS 8583 is used to facilitate financial transactions, such as payments at a point of sale or withdrawals from an ATM. If your goal is to arrive at a more secure solution for your web service, ISO 8583 is not the way to go.

I am currently working on a project where we use packet sniffing (similarly to Wireshark) to analyze network traffic and thereby providing a monitoring solution around systems running ISO 8583. We are able to view the entire message in the clear, so there is zero security benefits in using ISO 853 over JSON.

Instead, I would rather recommend enabling TLS/SSL on your web service. Alternatively, you could encrypt sensitive fields in the message yourself.

If you wanted to make an ISO 8583 message more secure, you should look at P2PE (Point-to-Point Encryption), where certain of the Cardholder Data fields are encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

ISO 8583 is a Financial transaction card originated message format. It does not apply to the JSON in the question.

Also it is not understood how "make the message more secure" applies?

Answer (score 1):

I afraid you will have to develop your own implementation JSON-Iso8583, i suggest implement an object like ISO8583 with a HashMap of fields but i don't know how json works with hasmaps or other collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can check JSONPackager class from jpos [ jpos.org ] framework.